# get_code_model() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'model' and 'company'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tengo problemas en la siguiente función

```
def get_code_model(model, company):
    count_model = model.objects.filter(company=company).count()
    posible_code = count_model + 1

    kwargs_model = {
        'company':company,
        'code': posible_code
    }
    is_not_exist_instance = False
    while is_not_exist_instance is False:
        try:
            exist_instance = model.objects.get(kwargs_model)
            posible_code += 1
            kwargs_model['code'] = posible_code
        except model.DoesNotExist:
            return posible_code
```

la cual me devuelve el siguiente error

```
get_code_model() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'model' and 'company'
```

la cual no logro hacer funcionar

Comment: Y como llamas a la función?

Comment: self.fields['code'].initial = get_code_model()

Comment: Si en la propia definición de la función especificas que hay que pasarle dos argumentos (model y company) no puedes llamar a la función así. Obviamente tienes que pasarle los dos argumentos.

Comment: Entonces por qie específicas 2 argumentos en la declaración? Deberías pasarle esos argumentos a menos que quieras que se usen las variables globales

Answer (score 0):

pues cuando se especifican los parametros de una funcion tal como tu lo hiciste en get_code_model con model y company; siempre que quieras invocar a la funcion deberas indicar tantos argumentos como parametros tiene la funcion de otra forma arrojara error. es un tema de sintaxis.
si deseas una funcion con parametros no obligatorios entonces puedes hacer lo de la siguiente manera

```
def mi_funcion(*args):
      print("holamundo")
      print("Estos son mis argumentos indefinidos:",args)

mi_funcion()
mi_funcion("casa","perro")
mi_funcion("pepe","pepo","pipo")
```

entonces en este caso args sera la variable definida dentro de la funcion que contendra todos los argumentos que se entregue a la funcion al invocarla.
las tres llamadas anteriores seran validas y no arrojaran error.